# Create a second variable from the first variablbe

Tags: powershell, variables, o365security-compliance

I'm trying to run a command again some mailboxes, after obtaining the mailbox names from a Retention Compliance Policy.

I can export the GUID to a CSV and then call the CSV, but I'm trying to limit my use of CSV's
The Below works with a CSV file

```
$Accounts = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\MailboxInfoGUID.csv'
ForEach($Account in $Accounts)
{
$Guid = $null
$Guid = @()
$Guid = $Account.ArchiveGuid
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity $Guid -FullCrawl}

$Users = Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy $LabelPolicyName - 
DistributionDetail | Select - ExpandProperty ExchangeLocation | Select - 
ExpandProperty Name
```

I'd like to run the command without using a CSV file, but to get the mailbox identity I need to look in the Compliance Policy

How can I use the mailbox names obtained from the policy to then run a crawl on the mailbox

Comment: So `Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy ` is where you're getting the mailboxes from?

Comment: Yes that's Correct

Comment: assign that to `$Accounts`

Comment: How would that work exactly?

Comment: you wouldn't need to export to a csv if you assigned it to `$accounts` which loops through it using the `.ArchiveGuid` property, or am I mistaken about the origins of that property?

Comment: What are you using to export to 'C:\Temp\MailboxInfoGUID.csv'?

Comment: I use Get-Mailbox to obtain the GUID and save this to a CSV., I'd like to obtain the mailbox name from Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy and then iterate through these values to then obtain the GUID from the Get-Mailbox command and then run the crawl

Comment: That's a little confusing. Can you rephrase as I'm thrown off from "*I'd like to obtain it from Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy and then iterate through these values to then obtain the GUID from the Get-Mailbox command and then run the crawl*". Obtain what?

Comment: Obtain the mailbox names from Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy command, then for each mailbox in the policy I want to run Get-Mailbox 'MailboxNameFromPolicy' -FullCrawl

Comment: To rephrase: You would like to get the output from `Get-Mailbox` and assign that directly to `Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy` to obtain the GUID from it? Then use that GUID to do the crawl?

Comment: No, Get the Mailbox from the Compliance Policy then run Get-Mailbox on the mailbox name from the policy to start the full crawl

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, you would like the following:

1. Get the mailboxes from `Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy`.
2. Iterate through each of those mailboxes grabbing the GUID property.

   - Using `Get-Mailbox`.
3. Pass the newly obtained GUID to `Start-ManagedFolderAssistant`.

Given that's what you're after, the following should work:

```
(Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy $LabelPolicyName -DistributionDetail).ExchangeLocation.Name | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity (Get-Mailbox -Identity $_).ArchiveGuid -FullCrawl
    }
```

Due keep in mind that I don't have the [ExchangePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps) module installed so I am going off just logic; *you may have to adjust the properties*.

Comment: Thank you, its not identifying the mailbox. The error is

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "37627d32-1763-4ec9-b8af-8bb1263594e9" value of type "System.Guid" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxOrMailUserIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-ManagedFolderAssistant], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Start-ManagedFolderAssistant
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Comment: @ChrisMullins, the `Get-Mailbox` isn't? Is the `(Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy $LabelPolicyName -DistributionDetail).ExchangeLocation.Name` the names of the mailboxes?

Comment: Ahh I see, try converting it to a string: `(Get-Mailbox -Identity $_).ArchiveGuid.ToString()`